# Doctrine: добавление параметров к уже установленным

Tags: php, doctrine2

С помощью QueryBuilder я могу добавить какое-либо условие к уже добавленным и не заменить их:

```
if (isset($params['cityId'])) {
    $qb->andWhere('c.city = :cityId');
}
if (isset($params['categoryId'])) {
    $qb->andWhere('c.categoryId = :catId')
}
```

Но добавленные параметры замещают старые.
Я не въехала в документацию, или в этом действительно нет необходимости и параметры действительно всегда добавляются скопом?
А если я хочу все разбить на методы?

Есть ли смысл использовать:

```
$parameters = $qb->getParameters();
$parameters[] = new Parameter('cityId', $params['cityId']);
$qb->setParameters($parameters);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine QueryBuilder позволяет устанавливать параметры не только "пачкой" но и по одному. Для этого используется метод [`QueryBuilder::setParameter`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.5/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Query.QueryBuilder.html#_setParameter) (обратите внимание на отсутствие "*s*" в конце имени метода).

Пример использования:

```
$query_builder->setParameter(':city_id', 123);
```

Comment: Разве setParameter() не затрет старые данные?
Хмм... я видимо делала что-то не так, ибо когда использовала что-то типа
$qb->setParameter('cityId', $cityId)
   ->setParameter('catId', $catId);
то мне выдавало "мало параметров - 1, нужно 2"

Comment: А с чего он должен затирать старые данные? Единственный возможный случай, это когда вы дважды передаете параметр с одним и тем же именем.

Comment: Дописала комментарий выше. Видимо у меня были проблемы где-то в другом месте. Теперь понятно, что ->setParameter() ничего не затирает. Спасибо